# Swift 4 - MQTT receive constantly messages

Tags: swift, raspberry-pi, mqtt, subscribe

I want to update a label in my swift app constantly with a distance-value I get from my raspberry. The configuration of the raspberry works fine and it publish me the value as a string every second, so I can receive it with MQTT.
Now I run out of ideas how to subscribe to this value. Do I need some kind of loop? Everything I tried the debugger found nil inside my subscription. 
Is there a possibility to let my app know, when a message received? 
My code (snippet)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureMQTT()
    mqttClient.subscribe(distanceTopic, qos: .qos1)

func configureMQTT() {
    let clientID = "IPhoneTest"
    let host = "192.168.2.105"
    let port = UInt16(1883)
    mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: host, port: port)
    mqttClient.username = ""
    mqttClient.password = ""
    mqttClient.keepAlive = 60
    mqttClient.delegate = self
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16 ) {
    if (message.topic == distanceTopic){
       print(message.string!)
```

I know it is nil, because it only subscribes one time after starting the app. I can't set the subscription to an action, so do I need a loop or sth like this? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that you've assigned `self` as the delegate? I don't see that in the code above. When you say "Everything I tried the debugger found nil inside my subscription," what does that mean? Is `mqtt(didReceiveMessage:)` being called? What's `nil` in that case? MQTT has a new interface where you can set `didReceiveMessage` rather than using a delegate if you like. Be sure to re-check the docs and start with the example project. Just hack the example project so it listens to your topic and prints the results.

Comment: Yeah I tried to receive a message by pushing a "test button". This button sends a message to the pi and the pi to my app. This works fine. The only thing I don't know is how I can tell my app to "wait" for a message without setting an action like a button

Comment: Edited the code.

Comment: Does `didReceiveMessage` get called for every message, one message, or no messages? When you say "found nil inside my subscription" do you mean that the method gets called repeatedly, but something (what?) is nil? You shouldn't need to subscribe multiple times. You should keep getting callbacks until you unsubscribe.